# What is the aternative of Delay function in C or more precisely in STM32?

Tags: c, arduino, stm32, delay

I'm programming a STM32 nucleo board in C and I want to insure that a button must be pressed for a certain amount of time before interpreting the result as a particular state. In other word making sure the pin that I'm reading is a constant signal.

At first, I thought about using a Delay function (I'm a noobie) but whenever I look in the internet to find some ideas no mater if it's a Arduino, STM or C language forum they all push to not use it anymore. It's like Delay is only good for your very first code when you try to blink a led, after that you must not use it anymore..

Anyway I wonder if you guys know a great alternative to the delay function

Comment: [Timers](https://www.digikey.com/en/maker/projects/getting-started-with-stm32-timers-and-timer-interrupts/d08e6493cefa486fb1e79c43c0b08cc6)?

Comment: Search for "stm32 button debounce" or similar

Comment: First of all you need to check for bouncing, the button may connect and disconnect rapidly in the first few milliseconds. So if the polling of the button indicates that the state of the button have changed from not pressed to pressed, then skip polling for a few microseconds. Then poll the state once every 10 milliseconds or so. If the button haven't changed state for 100 polls, then it has been pressed for one second.

Comment: It depends on what your software is suppoded to do besides detecting a button press. If you use an operating system you might have to define processes/tasks/runnables, and there are probably functions to let your task sleep allowing the CPU to do other tasks. Otherwise you would have to find a way to manage all tasks the software has to do concurrently. A delay function can be used if you can do everything in a simple loop and if there is nothing else to do for some time.

Comment: There are lots of ways to debounce buttons, and everyone has their favourite way. I really like [this method](https://hackaday.com/2015/12/10/embed-with-elliot-debounce-your-noisy-buttons-part-ii/).

Answer (score 0):

The usual answer is replace `delay()` with `millis()`. Which is <s>wrong</s> not the full story.

`loop()` is called loop because it runs again and again. Optimally not taking any time per round, but infinitely often.

It's a *completely different approach*, as it does not matter that the lines of the loop are executed one after the other, until "the program" is finished at the end of loop(). It's rather a description, what the controller should do at any given state of the real world around and the machine itself.

This state description requires some variables to be kept from one loop round to the next, to be able to detect changes. By remembering when something happened you can find out the time passed since then. (Here `millis` is a useful function. Always used in a difference between the actual millis value and the remembered one.)

BTW: Arduino programming is done in C++, not C